# how to avoid sending client_id and client_secret as parameters in oauth for slack?

Tags: slack-api

Slack says as below.(https://api.slack.com/methods/oauth.v2.access)

> If at all possible, avoid sending client_id and client_secret as parameters in your request.

But if I remove client_id or client_secret I got invalid_client_id or bad_client_secret. How can I resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized it by using the HTTP basic authentication. (I set the client_id and client_secret in the url like http://{client_id}:{client_secret}@...)